# OpenCV puttext curved text printing

Tags: python, image, opencv, text, curve

I am trying to print text in curved way instead of straight line using opencv puttext function.
Can lineType supports curve option instead of cv2.LINE_AA?
Any other alternatives available to print curved text on an image?

```
Syntax: cv2.putText(image, text, org, font, fontScale, color[, thickness[, lineType[, bottomLeftOrigin]]])

Parameters:
image: It is the image on which text is to be drawn.
text: Text string to be drawn.
org: It is the coordinates of the bottom-left corner of the text string in the image. The coordinates are represented as tuples of two values i.e. (X coordinate value, Y coordinate value).
font: It denotes the font type. Some of font types are FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, , etc.
fontScale: Font scale factor that is multiplied by the font-specific base size.
color: It is the color of text string to be drawn. For BGR, we pass a tuple. eg: (255, 0, 0) for blue color.
thickness: It is the thickness of the line in px.
lineType: This is an optional parameter.It gives the type of the line to be used.
bottomLeftOrigin: This is an optional parameter. When it is true, the image data origin is at the bottom-left corner. Otherwise, it is at the top-left corner.

Return Value: It returns an image.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353576/curved-text-rendering-in-matplotlib

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62732543/whats-the-best-way-to-arc-bend-a-text-image

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70090460/how-would-i-warp-text-around-an-images-edges/70104312#70104312 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68979045/how-can-i-draw-a-curved-text-using-python-converting-text-to-curved-image/68986570#68986570

Comment: Set to True `bottomLeftOrigin = True`.   When it is true, the image data origin is at the bottom-left corner. Otherwise, it is at the top-left corner.

Comment: that wasn't the question though, @toyotaSupra

Comment: Oops! OP  talking about curved but not a straight line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `cv::putText()` does not support that.